# What is the probability of successfully leveling a character's attack stat to a given value over $x$ rolls in the dice RPG Too Many Bones?

Tags: probability, dice

Too Many Bones is a "dice-builder" RPG that has the following rule for leveling up a character's attack stat:

The player must roll a number of D6 equal to the character's current attack value. If no 1's are rolled, the level-up is successful.

It follows that for a character with 1 attack, the probability of success is $\frac{5}{6}$. For a character with 2 attack, the probability of success is $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2$, and so on. Given this rule, what is the most likely number of attempts it would take to get a character from 1 attack to 6 attack?

I wrote a script to simulate the process and found that for this particular scenario the distribution peaks at 7 rolls (a frequency of $\approx 16\%$). How would one arrive at this result analytically?

More abstractly, given the rules of the game, what is the most likely number of rolls $x \in \mathbb{N}$ it would take to level a character from an attack value of $a$ to an attack value of $b$?

Comment: The rule is not entirely clear.  It would appear that you intend for a character to "level up" in stages.  So a character with $1$ attack point must first become a character with $2$ attack points, before proceeding to level up further.  In such a scenario the "expected number of attempts" to go from $a$ level to $b$ level is the sum of the expected number to go from $a$ level to $a+1$ level and the expected number to go from $a+1$ level to $b$ level.  So you can focus on the expected number needed to level up one step at a time.

Comment: One further clarification of what you ask: "what is the most likely number of rolls".  Do we count the number of attempts, each involving a certain number of dice that depends on the character's level, or do we count the (total) number of dice rolled in all attempts?

Comment: @hardmath - Thanks for pointing out my oversight. Yes, you must succeed at each level before proceeding to the next. To your second point, perhaps my choice of the word "rolls" is overloaded. Let's call the process of a level $n$ character rolling $n$ D6 an "attempt." I'm curious how many attempts one might expect to make in leveling from $a$ to $b$. Thanks for your input!